# How can i get one object - file by id from aws s3 bucket with their aws sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

If i want to get all files from specific bucket.

```
 var bucketParams = {
        Bucket : 'the-bucket-name'
      };
      
      // get all files from specific bucket
      s3.listObjects(bucketParams, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success *", data.Contents);
        }
      });
```

Is there any way  - method to get some file by id ? I don't want to get all of them and then to filter by id or name - so to search for unique one ,i want this to be done on the DB side.
I am using nodejs.

Comment: The unique identifier for objects stored in Amazon S3 is the object's `Key`. This is similar to a filename, and it is unique to each object within a bucket. You say you want a "method to get some file by id" -- do you mean to **download** the object, or just to retrieve information about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **listObjectsV2** to get some files bypassing selection criteria in params.

```
var params = {
  Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Delimiter: 'STRING_VALUE',
  MaxKeys: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
  Prefix: 'STRING_VALUE',
  StartAfter: 'STRING_VALUE'
}
s3.listObjectsV2(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property

Comment: You can send key details to prefix param - which will fetch only matching files with defined prefix